# Puppet: Execute script relative to file

Tags: mac-osx, puppet

I'm totally new to Puppet, so I'm sorry if this question isn't even well-formed haha. I'm trying to use Boxen to set up my new Macbook Pro. I've found a [script](https://github.com/kcrawford/dockutil) that will help me manipulate what is in the dock. I wasn't sure how to run it, so I just copied it into the `script` directory in my Boxen repo. Then, I tried to use it as follows:

```
# Public: Add a new app to the dock
define dock-app($app = $title) {
    exec { "Add $app to dock":
        command => '/opt/boxen/repo/script/dockutil add',
    }
}

# Public: Remove all existing apps from the dock
class my-osx::dock::clear() {
    exec { 'Clear existing dock app':
        command => '/opt/boxen/repo/script/dockutil remove --all',
    }
}
```

And then I would use it as follows in `manifests/site.pp`:

```
  include webstorm
  include chrome
  include chrome::canary

  include my-osx::dock::clear

  dock-app { '/Applications/"Google Chrome".app': }
  dock-app { '/Applications/"Google Chrome Canary".app': }
  dock-app { '/Applications/Webstorm.app': }
  dock-app { '/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app': }
```

(Again, I really have no idea what I'm doing, so please tell me a better way if you know of one haha.)

This appears to run without error, however, I have some outstanding questions:

- I'm not happy with the necessity of using an absolute path to find the `dockutil` script. Is there an equivalent of `__dirname` in node, where you can get the directory of the current file you're in?
- Is there a better way to ask packages like `webstorm` where they will be installed to, instead of hardcoding a path?
- Is there a better place for the `dockutils` script to live?

Thanks!

**However gave me a drive-by downvote:** Mind leaving some feedback so I can improve?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not happy with the necessity of using an absolute path to find the dockutil script.

You could partly address this by setting up resource default for your exec.  Specifically you could set a path.  Set something like this perhaps?

```
Exec {
  path => ['/opt/boxen/repo/script/', '/usr/sbin', '/usr/bin', '/sbin', '/bin']
}
```

If created a custom fact to report the directory of your `dockutils` script on the remote host you could re-write your configuration like this.  You do have to be a bit careful about this.  It is remotely possibly you could have a invalid/corrupt fact value.

```
define dock-app($app = $title) {
    exec { "Add $app to dock":
        command => "$::dockerpath/dockutil add",
    }
}
```